# How can I count the arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have tried Scanner to read a text file into an arraylist.
Let's assume that I have an arraylist like this

```
[A, MANBA]
[A, PGD]
[A, GUSB]
[A, GLB1]
[B, HS6ST1]
[B, NDST1]
[B, NDST4]
[C, NRP1]
[C, ZEB1]
```

How can I count the occurrence of the first value and print it out ?
As this particular example, the output will be

```
A  4
B  3
C  2
```

Here is the code I have so far. Any suggestion would be grateful.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PI_list{
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("/home/tab.csv"));
    while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> PPIData = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\t");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            PPIData.add(scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println(PPIData);
    }

    inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the count for A be 4 in your example?

Comment: Don, you're right. A should be 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method with simple for

```
public String countOccurences(String letter,List<String> array){
  int counter = 0; 
  for(String s : array){
      if(s.equals(letter))
        counter++;
   }
  return letter + ": " + String.valueOf(counter);
}

public void getResult(List<String> array){
  Set<String> setOfLetters = new HashSet<String>();
  List<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(String s: array){
     s.replace("[","");
     s.replace("]","");
     String tab[] = s.split(",");
     setOfLetters.add(tab[0]);
     dateArray.add(tab[0]);
 }
 for(String s: setOfLetters)
    countOccurences(s,dataArray);
}
```

so simply your code should look like that

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("/home/tab.csv"));
    while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> PPIData = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\t");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            PPIData.add(scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();
        getResult(PPIData);
        System.out.println(PPIData);
    }
```

Of course with access to my above methods.

Merging it all your class should look like

```
public class PI_list {

    public static String countOccurences(String letter, List<String> array) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (String s : array) {
            if (s.equals(letter))
                counter++;
        }
        return letter + ": " + String.valueOf(counter);
    }

    public static void getResult(List<String> array) {
        Set<String> setOfLetters = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : array) {
            s.replace("[", "");
            s.replace("]", "");
            String tab[] = s.split(",");
            setOfLetters.add(tab[0]);
            dataArray.add(tab[0]);
        }
        for (String s : setOfLetters)
            System.out.println(countOccurences(s, dataArray));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("/home/tab.csv"));
        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            ArrayList<String> PPIData = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\t");
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                PPIData.add(scanner.next());
            }
            getResult(PPIData);
            System.out.println(PPIData);
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, I still don't know where should i put this for loop ? just before the second while loop ?

Comment: Look on my above post again. I wrote more.

Comment: Do you mean add your method before or after to the main function ? What do you mean by access to the method ?

Comment: Access it means you have to put them into class that method main is run. So simply in class `PI_list`. But I think that you have to change accessors of that methods for `public static...`. Thansk in advance for accepting answer. :)

Comment: i know i have to put it into PI_list class, but I don't know how/where. I have tried to put it into the second while loop but failed. Maybe it looks trivial to you, but I really stuck over this.  I'm really at very beginning stage of Java. It takes me two days to reach here.

Comment: I merged it for you. Please have a look.

Comment: thanks for your help. However, It seems that still doesn't work.

Comment: At first I keep getting error message like this :
    <blink>
    'P_list.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    public static String countOccurences(String letter, List<String> array) {
                                                        ^
    symbol:   class List
    location: class P_list'
    </blink>

Comment: I tried 'String countOccurences(String letter, ArrayList<String> array)' instead ,and it works. However, that is not what I expect. The result would be like : 
A: 1
MANBA: 1
PGD: 1
A: 1
GUSB: 1
A: 1
A: 1
GLB1: 1

Comment: So simply try to debug that code and see what is wrong :-) upvote is appriciated because of lot of work that i put into.

Comment: @Rafik911 I really really appreciate your help. There is only the last step. Could you please help ?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [guavas `MultiMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap). That's exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code

```
while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> PPIData = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\t");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            PPIData.add(scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println(PPIData);
    }

    inputFile.close();
    }
```

The arraylist is locally scoped so you can't use it outside the while loop.

In case you want to use it later some point to count the occurances of letter, then declare it above the while loop.

**Steps for solution:**

1. Iterate through the arrayList
2. Get the first element which will contain [A, MANBA] as string
3. Split the string based on comma, get the value A
4. Now pass the value A to a function where you will check the occurrences of A in the ArrayList.

Mostly this will give you concurrency exception as you will be processing same arraylist.

Better solution:

Use  guava-libraries Multimap which will be easier for your scenario

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. I'm very new in coding java. I guess I understand what you mean, but still don't know how to do. I prefer your four steps solution, by the way.